# Trigger bootstrap popover inside onclick event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i manage to trigger the popover inside the onclick event?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('[rel=popover]').popover().click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
});


<button class="btn" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="manual" data-content="somecontent" data-original-title="Title" type="button" onclick="if(something==true) { console.log($(this));$(this).popover('show'); }">Start</button>
```

This just gets me an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: It works here. I guess you have a conflict with a another library or not have jQuery loaded at all .. (??)

Comment: Yeah it works. Popover opens after dropping the Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: I mean, no errors is raised when I place the code into a clean TB. I always use a "fresh" TB when checking code here from SO, so i guess the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem. Go downward analytically. Can you create a fiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your onclick and you can specify the trigger inside of your options according to the docs http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({trigger:'click'})
```

Or specify it inside your html

```
<button class="btn" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click"
```

Comment: i knew that. please look at my code. i need to execute some js before triggering the popover. also i dont execute that js on all popovers.